# VBA MKDIR in SharePoint fails

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

Here is my issue:

I am trying to make a folder in a SharePoint shared document library.  But it only works after I enter my credentials using the "open with windows explorer" menu item.

My users will not understand if I tell them they need to do this first. So, my questions is either: 
(A) is there a way to force this credential popup from VBA   OR...
(B) is there a way to pass these credentials through VBA

```
myWorkbookBasePath= "\\sharepoint.buckeye.com\sites\transportation\cc\pipelineoperationreports\Shared%20Documents\" & folder


MkDir myWorkbookBasePath
```

[image]

Comment: Use FTP protocol or map the site as a network drive using `WScript.Shell` instead, you can use an InputBox to ask for credentials if required or you can hard code them.

Comment: I don't think I want to map this drive to everyone's PC.  can you explain using an FTP protocol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What credentials would you use if you could provide them programmatically? If you can answer that, you could try something like this:

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "Z:", "\\server\share", False, strUser, strPwd

MkDir "Z:\NewFolder"
...
objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "Z:"
```

Comment: This worked for me but is causing issues - I used Z in a file and it works fine, however, I tried the same thing after renaming the file and it doesn't work unless I use another drive (I get an authentication error) ?? I don't want to have to use another drive for every time I rename a file that uses the same folder location!