# create folder in sharepoint document library using VBA

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010, vba

I am trying to create a folder in sharepoint Documents library using Excel VBA. Here is my code which is not working

```
 Sub CreateFolder_SP()

 Dim strURL As String

''Copy and paste the URL of your sharePoint folder where you want to create another folder

  strURL = "http://sharepoint link/"

 'strURL = Replace(strURL, "http:", "") //// have also tried this

 strURL = Replace(Replace(strURL, "http:", ""), "/", "\")

Dim Fld_r As String

 Fld_r = "Test"
 Fld_r = Replace(Fld_r, Chr(9), " ")

 If Len(Dir(strURL & Fld_r, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then ''' I am getting run-time error here bad File name or number or sometimes path not found
  MkDir (strURL & Fld_r)
  DoEvents

 End If
 End sub
```

Comment: You can't (to my knowledge) use `MkDir` and `Dir` on Sharepoint locations unless you've mapped a 'traditional drive mapping' to the location. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074253/vba-mkdir-in-sharepoint-fails

Comment: Any other way to do this other that MkDir or Dir

Comment: I've since seen comments suggesting it *is* possible to do this using MkDir directly (i.e. without a mapping) but I've yet to test it. I'll have a go (during the week) and come back to this thread if it works.